Sci-fi book in which an artist with polio is abducted by aliens, cured of his infirmity, and joins an interstellar crew
Looking for a science fiction book, probably from the 50s or 60s. I read it in middle school in 1990-91.
The protagonist is an artist who suffered from polio, but when he is abducted by aliens, they fix his body. He developed a manic- like energy to counter his deformity. He is recruited by aliens because of this, and they cure his infirmity. He joins an interstellar crew, as the lowest person in the hierarchy. He has to fight all of the other crew to become the new captain of the ship.
The ship is part of a massive force working to save the galaxy from an invasive enemy that is seeking to destroy the entire galaxy for resources. The ship is called the tow boat or the rowboat?

Hour of the Horde, a novel by Gordon R. Dickson which was also the answer to the old question Sci-fi novel about man picked up by aliens to represent earth in battle against galactic invaders; first published (perhaps in a shorter version) in Venture Science Fiction, May 1969, available at the Internet Archive. The complete novel can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive. Does any of these covers ring a bell?
ISFDB Synopsis:

Annihilating everything before it, a horde of monstrous space travellers were advancing through the stars. And Earth lay in their route. To defend their home planets, the worlds that lay in the path of the monsters created a super defense force, asking each planet to contribute one especially talented warrior to help turn the invaders away. Miles Vander was Earth's man, but when he arrived at the rendezvous point he found that he was included in the special task force of the less civilized defenders. But in the contest of advanced nuclear weaponry and computer strategy, it turned out to be Vander's group that had the special independent qualities and the raw courage to meet the challenge most effectively. (from the back cover of the DAW Books first printing)

The hero, Miles Vander, is an artist crippled by polio:

It had happened again. That primitive, unconquerable power in him that he could not seem to deny had reached out once more, savagely, down the muscles of his good arm and hand, to take over his painting.
Exhausted, Miles Vander threw the number four brush he held, now bloodily tipped with alizarine red, back into the pint fruit jar of muddy turpentine holding the other long, yellow-handled brushes. A feeling of dull exhaustion and frustration dropped on him like the doubled folds of some heavy blanket.
All at once he was aware again of his own starved-looking body, his bent shoulders, his uselessly hanging left arm that polio had crippled six years ago.

The President goes on TV to deliver the message of the aliens:

"Our visitors have told us," he said, "that defense of the galaxy is a common duty. For our world to join in that defense is therefore a duty. What they require from us, however, is a contribution of a highly specialized nature." His voice hesitated and then went on more strongly. "They tell us that the weapons with which our galaxy's defensive force will meet the Horde are beyond the understanding of our science here on Earth. They tell us, however, that they are part physical, part nonphysical in nature. The number of fighting individuals we can contribute, therefore, to our galaxy’s defense is limited by our relatively primitive state of awareness as far as these nonphysical forces are concerned. We can send only one man. This one individual—this one man who is best suited to be our representative by natural talent and abilities—has already been selected by our visitors. He will shortly be taken over by them, adjusted so as to make the best possible use of these talents, and then turned loose for a brief period to move about our world and absorb an identification with the rest of us. This process of absorbing an identification has been compared by our visitors to the process of charging a car battery, to exposing its plates to a steady input of electrical current. Once he has been so 'charged,' all of us on this world who have managed to contribute to the 'charging' will continue to have some sort of awareness in the backs of our minds of what he is going through up on the battle line, to which he will then be transported. And from this linkage he will draw the personal nonphysical strength with which he will operate his particular weapon when the encounter with the Horde occurs."

Needless to say, Miles is selected to represent Earth. He is not abducted, he gives his consent. The aliens cure him:

"What's happened to me?" he asked wonderingly.
"You are now completely healthy. That's all," said the taller alien.

Miles is assigned to a ship crewed by beings from primitive worlds, who fight a lot:

Miles had come back to the room of the ship in which he had awakened. Chak'ha was still there, lying on his bunk. But when Miles had started to question him about the pecking order, the combats, and the relationship of all this to the coming of the Silver Horde, he had felt unhappiness rising from the lax body of the alien like a cloud of sickness.
"There's just nothing to do," Chak'ha said, looking away from him now, looking at the blank inner wall of his bunk. "There's just nothing else to do."
"Nothing to do but fight with each other?" Miles demanded. "No training to be done? No practicing with our weapons? No practicing with the ship itself? What kind of fighting ship is this?"
"Tt isn't a fighting ship," said Chak'ha to the wall. "It's the Fighting Rowboat."
"The Fighting Rowboat?"
"That's what we all call her," muttered Chak'ha.

